# how to use both UIImagePickerController and PHPicker by adding #available

Tags: swift

PHPickerViewController is supported only from iOS 14.0. If your app has a deployment target of iOS 13.0 and less, you still have to use UIImagePickerController.how can i use that can anybody share some KT

Answer (score 2):

**PHPicker Function IOS14**

```
@available(iOS 14, *)
extension UIViewController : PHPickerViewControllerDelegate{

func pickPhoto(limit : Int , delegate : PHPickerViewControllerDelegate){
    // new in iOS 14, we can get the asset _later_ so we don't need access up front
    do {
        // if you create the configuration with no photo library, you will not get asset identifiers
        var config = PHPickerConfiguration()
        // try it _with_ the library
        config = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: PHPhotoLibrary.shared())
        config.selectionLimit = limit // default
        // what you filter out will indeed not appear in the picker
            config.filter = .any(of: [.images , .livePhotos]) // default is all three appear, no filter
        config.preferredAssetRepresentationMode = .current
        let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
        picker.delegate = delegate
        // works okay as a popover but even better just present, it will be a normal sheet
        self.present(picker, animated: true)
       // PHPhotoLibrary.shared().presentLimitedLibraryPicker(from: self)
    }
}


 func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        guard results.first != nil else {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }
        
        picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
            let prov = results.first!.itemProvider

            prov.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { im, err in
                if let image = im as? UIImage {
            // do whatever action with your image here
                  }
        }
 }
}
```

**UIImagePicker <iOS14**

```
extension UIViewController : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate , UINavigationControllerDelegate{
 
   func openGallary() {
        let localUIPicker = UIImagePickerController()
        localUIPicker.delegate = self as? UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary){
            localUIPicker.allowsEditing = false
            localUIPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
            self.present(localUIPicker, animated: true, completion: {})
        }
    }

 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    
            guard let choosenLogo = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
                return
            }
            // do whatever action with your image here


}   
}
```

**HOW TO USE**

```
// This Function call will launch picker according to compatible iOS version
// Inside Any ViewController Class call this function.

func showPhotos() {
        if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            pickPhoto(limit: 1, delegate: self)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            openGallary()
        }
        print("open photoLibary")
    }
```